# How to convert to keyboard characters

Tags: c#, .net, encoding

I have a text written with al kinds of weird characters, like `ŸŞşȘș€ÀÈÉÌÒÓÙàèéìòóùºª«»€` and I am trying to convert them to their normal equivalents, `SAEIOUaeiou` etc. I have tried this in a number of ways, but I keep getting mixed results, some work, some don't. This is what I've done so far:

```
byteArray1 = UnicodeEncoding.GetEncoding(1250).GetBytes(charArray);
byteArray2 = UnicodeEncoding.GetEncoding(852).GetBytes(charArray);
byteArray3 = UnicodeEncoding.GetEncoding(737).GetBytes(charArray);

resultArray1 = UTF7Encoding.GetEncoding(1250).GetChars(byteArray1);
resultArray2 = UTF7Encoding.GetEncoding(852).GetChars(byteArray2);
resultArray3 = UTF7Encoding.GetEncoding(737).GetChars(byteArray3);
```

Is there something simple and obvious (I doubt it) that I'm missing? Also, if I'm doing something really the wrong way, do tell.

Comment: Why are you creating encodings from specific subclasses? This will only confuse a reader. Just use `Encoding.GetEncoding()`.

Comment: I've tried in lots of ways, and this was the only one that partially worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you want to do is simply remove the diacritic marks from characters, I recommend you take a look at [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2006/10/30/removing-diacritics-accents-from-strings.aspx) which describes how to do so.

It will not do anything about characters such as `ºª«»€` though, but you can get rid of those after removing diacritics with a simple regular expression if you want:

```
var noDiac = RemoveDiacritics("ŸŞşȘș€ÀÈÉÌÒÓÙàèéìòóùºª«»€");
var cleanTxt = Regex.Replace(noDiac, "[^A-Z]", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
// outputs: YSsSsAEEIOOUaeeioou
```